# How prevent online payment fraud?

Tags: authorization, fraud, e-commerce

What is the solution of independent payment authorization from hackers between bank and merchant?
[image: Authorization fee]

Some banks used SOAP protocol. I need another solution.

Comment: Who are the actor here? Please explain the green and red connections. Is the Bank a payment processor?

Comment: I finding solution of guarantee bill is not changed. Only between bank and merchants

Comment: Do authorization and settling take place over separate channels? Is authorization made for an amount or just for a transaction? We need some details otherwise this reduces to the "Two Generals Paradox" which is unsolvable.

Comment: Authorization over separate channel. Banks send customer's amount value to merchant using this channel. Merchant check value If amount not changed when shipping the item.

Comment: Please recommend some solutions how do it and what type security mechanism is require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many cases the merchant can check the amount before shipping the item. However many payment gateways implement a checksum value that is hashed with a secret key and if the hash don't match the value the transaction is aborted. There are several flaws with this approach, I gave a presentation at blackhat asia last year that illustrate some of them. You can find the slides + code on my github: https://github.com/wireghoul/presentations/tree/master/BHAsia2014 and the talk is on YouTube, just search for solutum cumulus mediocris.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. The most secure way to do a payment with a hosted pci payment gateway using redirect is to use tokens where your website makes an API request that defines the amount, order id, etc and receives back a token. Next you redirect to the payment gateway using that token. Payment is complete and customer is redirected back to you with the same or a different token. You can now make an API call to determine the payment status of the token and compare all the details from the API call to the session details, they should match.